# How do I see the COUNT results for only the top values in the table and not the entire table in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, count, resultset

I am creating a Database for my utility bills in SSMS18, and I am trying to retrieve the count for the occurrence of a specific month in the top 10 months with the highest bills. How do I restrict the COUNT feature to only count the top number of rows?

### **Table design**

```
CREATE TABLE Electric (
                        [date] date NOT NULL, 
                        electric_bill_amount smallmoney);
```

**I can limit the results by adding a WHERE statement**

```
SELECT DISTINCT          DATENAME(MONTH, [date]) AS MONTH,
                         COUNT(DATENAME(MONTH, [date])) AS [Frequency]
FROM Electric
WHERE electric_bill_amount > 104
GROUP BY DATENAME(MONTH, [date])
ORDER BY [Frequency] DESC
```

but I would like to my query to be more dynamic and therefore only have the count statement use the months with the top 10 highest values.

Results should look something like this

```
August 3
September 3
July 2
January 1
December 1
```

Comment: Sorry I don't get the question. Do you like to have the top 10 months or should the counts only be identified by the top 10 bills for each month? Approach could be having a sub-query. So only select the top 10 rows (for example use [rank](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-window-functions/sql-server-rank-function/#:~:text=The%20RANK()%20function%20is,within%20a%20partition%20is%20one.) ) then you can group & count them perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I guess you are using SQL Server, not MySQL.
2. Just to clarify that you want to get the top 10 highest electric bill amount and see if each of these falls on which month.
3. Tested on [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=d43296e493e2190d133ada38cd763565)

```
SELECT         DATENAME(MONTH, [date]) AS MONTH,
               COUNT(DATENAME(MONTH, [date])) AS [Frequency]
FROM (
    SELECT [date], electric_bill_amount, RANK() OVER(ORDER BY electric_bill_amount DESC) as r
    FROM Electric
) tmp
WHERE r <= 10
GROUP BY DATENAME(MONTH, [date])
ORDER BY [Frequency] DESC;
```

Comment: This worked perfectly and sent me down the rabbit hole for researching window functions. Thank you.